# Same origin policy exception

Tags: iis, iframe, https, same-origin-policy

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:44300" from accessing a frame with origin "https://othersite". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

As you can see, both sites are https.

I am trying to access the properties of an iframe that is within my website. Could any one push me in the right direction?

Comment: localhost is different from othersite, 44300 is different from 443

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make sure that both sites run on *exactly* the same protocol, domain and port, you might think about using a proxy solution with your webserver.

Depending on the browsers and versions you need to support, you can choose CORS to solve the problem.